# Linq take returns zero elements from OData collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections, odata, take

I can't wrap my brain around this, I don't get why this behaves likes this.
I have made an OData query that returns a collection of 175 items

```
from c in navClient.Item where c.No != "" && c.Last_Date_Modified > dtfrom select c
```

**navClient.Item** is a System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery

However I want to take first 100 items from the collection using .Take(100) but get 0 items. It isn't until I do .Take(121) I get my first item, which is the first item in the collection, .Take(122) returns the first two items and so on.

Any idea why this behaves like this?

Edit:
Doing ToList first then Take(100) returns first 100 as expected.
My only theory right know is that the table I'm running my query against is just a temp table that is out of sync with the database.

Comment: What if you do a ToList first then do a take 100? Just to see...

Comment: If I convert to list first then do take(100) that I get 100 items no problem

Comment: Looks like a bug in DataServiceQuery or in your WCF Data Service

Comment: Is this your API? can you show us the controller implementation?

Comment: How exactly is your view going to be out of sync with the database?

Comment: You should also include more of your client code, this expression you have shown does not include the `Take` criteria, so it is plausible that the client is not sending the correct statement to the server at all.

Comment: A "View" is perhaps not the correct term, what I meant is that it might be a temporary table that contains prefetched data or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have described what looks like an issue in the server implementation that handles your request. This behaviour would occur if the `.Take(100)` was evaluated *before* the filter criteria. This issues can easily occur in the client *or* the server implementations. The `.ToList()` works because it brings back the *entire collection* to the client and then applies the filter criteria with standard *linq to objects* evaluation.

> *While not the cause today...*
> as a general rule, whenever you specify `.Take()` or `.Skip()` you should have also specified the explicit `.OrderBy()`, when the order is ambiguous in a limiting or paging query so too can be the results.

There are 3 common levels at play here:

1. **Client Query Resolution**
   Your linq query is first resolved into a URL that will be used to make the request to the API, you should first check that the URL is correctly constructed.

   You should be expecting a URL similar to:

   ```
   /odata/Item?$top=100&$filter=No ne '' AND Last_Date_Modified gt '2020-01-20T17:24:21.3605918+11:00'
   ```

   You can inspect the URL using the `.RequestUri` property on the query, try something like the following to capture it:

   ```
   var query = from c in navClient.Item 
               where c.No != "" && c.Last_Date_Modified > dtfrom 
               select c;
   query = query.Take(100);       
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((DataServiceQuery<Item>)query).RequestUri);
   ```

   The URL needs to through both the `$Top` and the `$filter` query options to the server.
2. **API Controller**
   The client is expecting the controller to handle or pass through both the `$filter` criteria *and* the `$top` expression to the underlying data store.

   Many default EF or *Unit of work* based OData implementations would simply return a proper `IQueryable<T>` expression using deferred execution. However if the backend store uses a repository pattern or the controller is otherwise constructing the dataset then that code may need to explicitly handle the `$filter` criteria *before* applying the `$top`

   > There are many simple OData controller examples out there that have a mocked `List<T>`  or otherwise `IEnumerable<T>` backend, the **red flag** is that if in the controller code you see a `.ToList()` or a `.AsQueryable()` on the main expression, or it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` response, then it indicates that the expression is *not* using deferred execution at all. This means that it most likely needs to manage the query options *manually*.
3. **OData Query Expression Resolver**
   Especially in the .Net Implementation, the `EnableQueryAttribute` by default applies the query options to the final *IQueryable* output immediately before or effectively as part of the serialization process.

   So the `$top` and `$filter` (and `$orderby`,`$select`,`$expand`) will be applied again even if the controller method has already evaluated these options. This isn't normally a problem, its a validation fail-safe and means that you do not strictly have to return `IQueryable<T>` from your controller methods at all.

   Due to this, if our backend supports deferred `IQueryable<T>` linq expressions (like `DbSet<T>` in an **EF** `DbContext`) then in the controller implementation we do not usually do anything with the query options, you let the `EnableQueryAttribute` process it for you.

   However, if the controller were to process the paging expression first `.Take(100)` and not apply the `$filter` correctly or at all, then the `EnableQueryAttribute` would apply the criteria to a list that had already been restricted, in your example, perhaps the first 100 items